# Slack API to retrieve last few messages posted in a channel using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

Can someone point me to documentation or code that uses no third-party nodejs libraries. basically, i want to print last few messages from a channel to console (events api - so my application can print each time a new message is posted as well.).

I am new to slack and the tutorials I have encountered are all using some 3rd party library. I want to perform this task just using the official slack nodejs sdk - no additional wrappers from third party.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the examples using nodejs in slack's documentation. https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tags/node.js

Comment: Everything there makes reference to some sort of library/framework. IBM Watson, Botkit, Google Cloud, AWS, Lamdas, stdlib, etc.

Comment: Even the article on making a oauth2 call via postman seems outdated, as I didnt get any option to specify redirect url when creating an app on slack.